# Vala loading headers locally

Tags: vala

My problem is that the generated .c file loads my headers inside <> instead of ""

The generated .c file has <my_header.h> instead of "my_header.h".
my_header.h is in the directory where are the vala files.

I tried using --includedir=. but that did not help.

This happens only with valac-0.16.0
Valac 0.16.1 does not have this bug.

I have to use valac-0.16.0,so swicthing the compiler version is not an option.

I fixed this using this script :

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

files = Dir.glob("*.c")
files.each do |f| 
    file = File.open(f,"r")
    data = file.read()
    data = data.sub("<my_header.h>","\"my_header.h\"")
    file2 = File.open(f,"w+")
    file2.write(data);
end
```

But this might fail when packaging it into a .deb file,so my question is still on.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `-X -I.` to the Vala compiler, which will pass `-I.` directly to the C compiler.

Comment: I am compiling vala to c file and then calling gcc.I fixed this by using sed (The ruby script also works but I ditched it for sed)